# Redirect to a Razor page at a specific location in an OnPost

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have an OnPost function of the form

```
public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    //Do some stuff

    return RedirectToPage("/Forms/Strategy");
}
```

This works properly and the RedirectToPage opens the Razor page at the top.  However, I would prefer the Redirect to open the Forms/Strategy page with a specific anchor point at the top of the browser window. That anchor is:

```
<h3><a id="RedirectTarget">Redirect Target</a></h3>
```

I have tried using a RedirectToPage of the form:

```
return RedirectToPage("/Forms/Strategy#RedirectTarget");
```

However, this results in an error:

> InvalidOperationException: No page named '/Forms/Strategy#returnstable' matches the supplied values.

I assume I am incorrectly structuring the URL for the RedirectToPage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the fragment for the generated URL using an [overload of `RedirectToPage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages.pagemodel.redirecttopage?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_RazorPages_PageModel_RedirectToPage_System_String_System_String_System_String_). Here's an example:

```
return RedirectToPage("/Forms/Strategy", null, "RedirectTarget");
```

The `null` argument above populates the `pageHandler` parameter, which just uses the default page handler.

Although `/Forms/Strategy` looks like a URL, it actually represents the page name, as a path that's relative to the `Pages` directory. When you attempt to use `/Forms/Strategy#RedirectTarget` as the page name, the route-generation process rightly fails to find a match.